# windows - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when accessing Apache log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code, which intends to constantly check apache log file and process the newly updated contents.

```
# detect.py
fp = open(r'C:\xampp\apache\logs\access.log', 'r')
... 
def follow(fp):
    fp.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            continue
        yield line
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loglines = follow(fp)
    for line in loglines:
        data = LogParser(line, db)
        ...
```

When I run this file, I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\core\detect.py", line 28, in <module>
    for line in loglines:
  File ".\core\detect.py", line 19, in follow
    line = fp.readline()
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have tried nearly all available means, such as: changing file privileges, running as administrators, killing all python related process before running this file ...
but I still get that error. I want to know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: is your file used by another process?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thank you. May it is because apache is updating access.log when I run this  python script? I'm sure that no other process using acess.log except apache.

Comment: maybe another instance of script is still running, take a look at task manager (or reboot computer)

Comment: AFAIK, Apache keeps its log file open. It is not a problem on a Linux host, because a file can be simultaneouly opened by different processes. But on Windows, the default mode is exclusive, and access will be denied for any other process. So I think that the way to go is to try to log to pipe if it is possible and use an auxilliary program to process log data and write it to a log file or to open the log file in non exclusive mode (search the WinAPI for CreateFile)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, you're right. I've tested my code on linux and it works fine. Thank you